# UITableViewCell height to expand according to UIImageview's aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, intrinsics

I am trying to have an UIImageview inside a UITableViewCell. the image shouldn't grow any wider than the safe area of the device and the height should grow any more than 350. Problem: the image scales properly, but the table view doesn't shrink in height to snuggle up against the image when its shorter than 350. I seek your advice, please

1. Set the imageview width to 414 and made it a high priority, Set the imageview to .scaleaspectFit.
2. Set the image vertical hugging priority to <= 350 at low priority.

I'm hoping to find a solution or guidance towards a solution to where the image will grow no more than the set height, don't know if this is good practice..
Also for the cell to shrink and snuggle against the image as it shrinks in height while still maintaining a constant width based on the device screen/safe area

Thank you all in advance

Some more code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let currentImage = images2[indexPath.row]
        let imageCrop = currentImage.getCropRatio()
        return tableView.frame.width / imageCrop

}

extension UIImage {
    func getCropRatio() -> CGFloat {
        var widthRatio = CGFloat(self.size.width / self.size.height)
        return widthRatio
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you kept your tableview cell height fixed?

Comment: I set it at 350 custom @BhargavR

Comment: You need to set the height of the cell according to the height of the image in the UITableView in 'heightForRowAt' data source method.

Comment: @BhargavR, I added these but no luck, thank you for responding
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let currentImage = images2[indexPath.row]
        let imageCrop = currentImage.getCropRatio()
        return tableView.frame.width / imageCrop
        
}

extension UIImage {
    func getCropRatio() -> CGFloat {
        var widthRatio = CGFloat(self.size.width / self.size.height)
        return widthRatio
    }
}

Comment: Keep the height calculation code as it is and remove both the image height related constraints and add only the bottom constraint from image to the content view of tableview cell. Please check this scenario once.

Comment: @BhargavR , thank you for the solutions and taking the time to answer. Happy coding :)